# set selected value of a drop down list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `dropdown list` with values

```
function getTests() {
  var html = '';
  $.get('/getTests', function (tests) {
       selTest = tests;
       html +=' <option value="">SELECT</option>';
       tests.forEach(function (test) {
          html += '<option value="' + test.id + '">' + test.names + '</option>'; 
       });
       $('#testnames').html(html);
  });
}
```

**html code :-**

```
<select class="lngcombo" id="testnames">
  <option value="">SELECT</option>
  <option value="25">email confirmation</option>
  <option value="72">ttutu</option>
  <option value="44">pagination</option>
</select>
```

while directing from another page am getting the value `test.id` as follows and want to get the value as selected in drop down

```
http://localhost:9080/history.html?testid=25
```

selected as  the dropdown value `email confirmation` based on the `testid=25`

For that I am doing following :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('testid') > -1){

       var testid = window.location.href;
       testid =testid.split('=');
       alert($("#testnames").val(testid[1]))
    }
});
```

but not getting the value as selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are loading the contents using an ajax request, you need to set the value once the ajax request is completed and the options are created.

So solution template could look like

```
function getTests(testId) {
    var html = '';
    $.get('/getTests', function (tests) {
        selTest = tests;
        html += ' <option value="">SELECT</option>';
        tests.forEach(function (test) {
            html += '<option value="' + test.id + '">' + test.names + '</option>';

        });
        $('#testnames').html(html);
        if(testId){
            $("#testnames").val(testId)
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('testid') > -1) {
        var testid = window.location.href;
        testid = testid.split('=');
        getTests(testid[1])
    }else{
        getTests()
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried with ur code.while redirecting from another page with value `http://localhost:9080/history.html?testid=25` value is not getting as slected

Comment: @Sush can you add a alert before the `if(testId){` and see what is the value of `testId`

Comment: it alerts the testid values 25 or 72 or 44

Comment: before i alerting `if(testId)` it first alerting testid value like 25 then alerting as `undefined`.when first alert coming it seems values as slected.then alerting undefined and selected value is not showing

Comment: why value is alerting undefined in second time

Comment: @Sush because the `getTests()` is called by some other code also - you  need to find who is calling it again and fix that

Comment: on the page load getTets() is calling for dislaying data in combo boxes

Comment: @Sush then the above dom ready logic need to be moved to there... instead of adding it as a separate handler

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48227/discussion-between-sush-and-arun-p-johny)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the alert here, just use:

```
$("#testnames").val(testid[1]);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D2Va6/1/)**

Comment: Check my fiddle, if not then there's probably something wrong with your `window.location.href` value or your generated HTML here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this scripts.

#### JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('testid') > -1){
        var testid = getParameterByName('testid');
        $('#testnames').val(testid);
    }
});

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this function on complete of ajax call, the case is different here, the js-function calls first and html renders later. So it's important to understand that we should render html first and then call our js-function. It will works for you.

```
alert($("#testnames").val(testid[1]).val());
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code
i have tested it

`var val = $(".lngcombo").val();       alert(val);`